# Why luarocks is it not starting?

Tags: lua, luarocks

When trying to start luaRocks i get error message:

[image]

I downloaded last version from http://luarocks.github.io/luarocks/releases/.

Then i try to run luarocks.exe. I use windows, vscode and lua 5.4.4

Comment: Good old luarocks error messages, useless as always. Your best chance is to just debug it yourself; it's usually just some dumb config line that's missing.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer

I do not quite understand what the configuration is, I just downloaded and ran it as in the official instructions

Comment: Read the stack trace:
It crashes because the assertion in file [`exists`](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/blob/master/src/luarocks/fs/lua.lua) failed since the path is nil.
Exists got called in [`local luadir_ok = fs.exists(cfg.variables.LUA_DIR)`](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/blob/master/src/luarocks/cmd.lua) so cfg.variables.LUA_DIR is nil. This looks indeed like a broken config. Search the config! You can also try to run as administrator in case luarocks has no access.